# Is there any (simple) way to have gitlab trigger a pipeline when the target branch of a merge request is updated

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I was looking at the docs for [Merged results pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html) where gitlab will create a new ref based on a merge of the source branch and target branch, and run the pipeline on that ref. So if your target branch for a merge-request was `main`, and your source branch was `topic`, and your git history looked like the following at the time you first created the MR:

```
        D topic
       /
      /
     /
A---B---C main
```

Then gitlab would create a merge commit of commit `C` and `D`, let's call it `E` to run the pipeline on:

```
        D topic
       / \
      /   E (gitlab pipeline runs on this commit)
     /   /
A---B---C main
```

If you later pushed a new commit (`F`) to `topic`, gitlab would again create a merge commit to run the pipeline on, and the git history would look like this:

```
        D---F topic
       / \   \
      /   E   G (2nd gitlab pipeline runs on this commit)
     /   /   /
A---B---C---' main
```

Note that in this example, `main` is still pointing to `C`, and `G` has parents: `C` and `F`.

My question is: If someone were to push a new commit `H` to `main`, without any other changes being pushed to `topic`, is there any way to get gitlab to automatically create a new pipeline for the MR based on a merge of `H` and `F`?